# Grab password from a file by searching username and store that password in variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a password file containing different username and associated password for that user

```
$ cat /apps/test_lab/.passwd
    amon: abc@321
    bmon: dgf@869
    cmon: ascd@!!@657
```

What I am trying to do is get the password by searching in a file using the username and store it in a variable

```
text = "cmon"
pswd_file = open("/apps/test_lab/.passwd", "r")
 for line in pswd_file:
     if re.match('(.+)'  +text+  '(.+)', line):
         print line
```

I am getting output as:

```
cmon: ascd@!!@657
```

While I want output like:

```
pswd_user="ascd@!!@657"
```

Can you help me with this? I am running as python 2.7.5.

Comment: Python2 is end of life next month. If you are new to it, then use Python3

Comment: Not really an answer but I thought it's worth pointing it out: **Storing passwords in plain-text is a very bad (and dangerous) habit.** If this is just an exercise then that's fine but if this is or is going to be a real application then please don't store passwords in a plain text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried a solution like:

```
import re
for line in open('/apps/test_lab/.passwd').readlines():
   line = line.strip()
   matchobj = re.match('^\s*(\w+)\:\s+(.*)$',line)
   username, password = matchobj.group(1,2)
   if username == 'cmon':
      print('pswd_user="'+password+'"')
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to split(':') with ':' and strip() to remove white spaces at both ends**

```
import re
text = "cmon"
pswd_file = open("testing.txt", "r")
for line in pswd_file:
    if re.match('(.+)'  +text+  '(.+)', line):
        pwd = line.split(':')[1]
        pwd = pwd.strip()
        print('pswd_user="'+ pwd +'"')
```